# Why Am I Going Through the Ground in Unity Game Engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am going through the Ground in my Unity Game Engine. Does anyone know why I am going through the ground. I am following the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEUhxe9vUOM&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuCVTz6lvhR81nnaf1a-b67U&index=6&ab_channel=CodinginFlow .

Here is my code for my PlayerMovement (I named it `PlayerMovementProject4.cs`):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementProject4 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb; //Will store appropriate Rigidbody2D from PlayerMovement
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;
    private float dirX = 0f;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;

    private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling}
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); //Might be appropriate to change to GetAxisRaw
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * 7f, rb.velocity.y);


        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
        UpdateAnimationUpdate();
        
    }

    private void UpdateAnimationUpdate() //Will be used to handle Animations
    {
        MovementState myMovementState;
        
        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            myMovementState = MovementState.running;
            sr.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            myMovementState = MovementState.running;
            sr.flipX = true;
        }
        else //Exactly 0
        {
            myMovementState = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > 0.1f)
        {
            myMovementState = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -0.1f)
        {
            myMovementState = MovementState.falling;
        }
        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)(myMovementState));
    }
    private void UpdateAnimationUpdate(float ff) //Might need to use this
    {
        dirX = ff;
        UpdateAnimationUpdate(); //DO NOT REPEAT CODE (DRY)
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);
        
    }
}
```

Also, here is a screenshot of the Error I am getting:

[image: My Error]

If anyone can help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking the collission matrix in project settings> Physics 2D, and the layer of your gameobject.

If it wasn't the collision matrix maybe check the collider component on your gameobject as well. Inorder to have an object not go through another object in 2D games, both object should have any kinds of Collider2d on it, and should uncheck the isTrigger.

Also when getting the NullReferenceException it means the script can't find the refference stuff it need to proceed, you should check if everything is properly added to the right gameobject or being properly created, I'm not sure if you know the log you are posting are not comming from your script, try identify where is came from first and see what went missing.